# Change HexaDecimal to Unicode in php

Tags: php, unicode, hex

How to convert hexal decimal to unicode in php?

I have a text like as:

```
"&#x129; &#x1EB1; &#xEC; &#x1ED9;"
```

and i want to convert to:

```
 "ĩ ằ ì à"
```

i already try : utf_decode or , mb_convert_encoding but seem nothing to change

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) actually

```
$str='"&#x129; &#x1EB1; &#xEC; &#x1ED9;"';
echo urldecode($str); //"prints" "ĩ ằ ì ộ"
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZNLLJZ)

Comment: when i display it in brower, it will show correctly, but when i show page source, it show "&#x129; &#x1EB1; &#xEC; &#x1ED9".

Comment: That is how it works why are you worried about that ?

Comment: i want to return json with this string but it display hexadecimal.. now i want to convert to unicode and send it to json